# Android Compatibility package with 3.0

Tags: android, compatibility

Does the android compatibility package return to default fragment usage if running 3.0+ or does it still use the package ones instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always uses the ones in the Android Support package.

Comment: Ok thanks, wasnt sure if part of the compatibility package had something where it checked the version and only applied the needed code on the older devices